# ExpressJS: Best way to separate routes and accepting params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, routes

I made a Express.js system where the files in the `/routes` folder are acting as a classic route (but with one file per route)

Example: `/routes/get/user.js` will be accessible with `http://localhost:8080/user` (the `/get` is to separate methods, it can be `/post`, `/put`...)

Here's my entire `index.js` file: https://pastebin.com/ALtSeHXc

But actually, my problem is that I can't pass params into the url like `https://localhost:8080/user/random_id_here`.

With this system, I think the best idea is to find a way to pass params on separated files too, but I don't know how can it be done...

Here's an example of one of my separated file:

```js
module.exports = class NameAPI {
    constructor(client) {
        this.client = client
    }

    async run(req, res) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Maybe you'll have a better system, or a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the file system as your repository for what routes are to be defined?  Is there something magical to you that just making a new file exist magically creates a new route the next time you restart your server?  Why not just build a table in your code that specifies everything and you can just loop over the table building routes from the table.  Then, you can put anything you want in the table definition, include params.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this from only the file sytsem, you could store something about  parameters as a property on your route handling function.  So, you import the function that will handle the route and then access properties on that function that specify things like params so you know how to build the Express route definition for that specific route.  Remember that functions are objects and can have properties.

Comment: Note: Your `_loadHttpMethode(method)` function can massively reduce the amount of code in it by factoring out the common part of each switch statement to a single function that take one parameter (the method name).  Everything else is just copied code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the optional params from the module object you already have so each module specifies its own params.  This example below shows just adding new params on after the module name, but you could extend this feature to be richer if you needed to.

In a simple implementation, in your loader, you can change this:

```
   posts.forEach((post) => {
        const module = new (require(`./routes/post/${post}`))(this);
        this.api.post(`/${post}`, async (req, res) => await module.run(req, res))
    })
```

to this:

```
   posts.forEach((post) => {
        const module = new (require(`./routes/post/${post}`))(this);
        const urlParams = module.params || "";
        this.api.post(`/${post}${urlParams}`, async (req, res) => module.run(req, res))
    });
```

So, if a given route wanted the extra URL param `/:id` added to it, then it would just define the `.urlParams` property on its exported module object to be `"/:id" and that would be automatically included in the route definition.

---

P.S. Most of the code in each of the branches of your `switch` statement in `_loadHttpMethode()` is identical.  With a little factoring into a common function and one or two parameters passed to that function, you can eliminate all the copied code among those different branches of the switch so all each switch does is call one function and pass it a few arguments.

Comment: For the last part, I did this: https://pastebin.com/7wZd55v0
Can it be better ? (Your code hasn't been added here, oops)

Answer (score 0):

I generally would setup my express to handle this way in that case you want a dynamic insert. This is personal code so do make the adjustments necessary or observe the behavior! :)

```js
WEBAPP.get('/room/:name', (req, res) => {
  // Check if URL ends with / (in my case I don't want that)
    if (req.url.endsWith('/')) return res.redirect('/');
  // Check if URL param "name" matches my regex ex. Username1920 or redirect them
    if (req.params.name.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,24}$/) === null) return res.redirect('/');
  // render the room (sending EJS)
    res.render('room', {
        title: req.params.name.toUpperCase()
    });
});
/*

/*This example accepts one param and must follow my regex/rules*/
```

So if you were handed /room/test12345 your req.params.name would return a value. Notice the colon to define a param, so you could have /:room/:user/:request and it'd return:
req.params.room, req.params.user, req.params.request all defined! :)

Comment: Hmm, the problem with that is that I need to add the params 1 by 1, no ? If yes, I want to try to avoid that, but if it's the only solution, I will try this :)

Comment: Order of operation so if you wanted /:room and /:room/:user and /:room/:user/:id this would need to be set. Otherwise with just /:room/:user/:id if you passed /newroomname/209593 you'd error out but /newroomname/209593/20 would reach!!!! This can be a post/get/etc command up-to you.

Comment: Each : represents a parameter and must be fulfilled if you expect several parameters in the links URL. :)

Answer (score 0):

### How to seperate routes and parse request parameter in express API

You can just put all your different API methods for each model in a seperated folder, and then just parse the API routes in your main file.

Let's say we have one main file called app.js, and you can organize your API routes/endpoints in subfolders.

**folder structure:**

```
├── app.js
└── routes
    └── api
        └── users.js
```

`users.js` in the folder `routes/api` in this case contains all operations for your users endpoint, and you import this in your `app.js` file.

Based on the route examples defined below, this will let you parse your express API with these endpoints:

```
GET YOUR_API:PORT/users           // fetch all users
GET YOUR_API:PORT/users/:userId   // fetch single user by id
```

**app.js**

```
// this is just a demo app.js, please adapt to your needs
const express = require("express");

// express app
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// api routes
// endpoint No. 1, this will create the endpoint /users
// and will enable you to use all methods defined in file users.js
app.use("/users", require("./routes/api/users"));

// add more endpoints, example endpoint No. 2
app.use("/ENDPOINT_NAME", require("./routes/api/FILE_NAME"));

// handle everything else you need to handle in your main file

// run server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

in subfolder routes/api you add your api route files, like so:

**routes/api/users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// here we only GET all users and user by id, 
// but you can add any endpoints required for your API.

// get all users
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // do something to get all users
        const allUsers = // fetch all users, depends on how you want to do it
        return res.status(200).json(allUsers)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Bad request.' })
    }
})

// get a specific user by Id from request parameters
router.get('/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // user id from params
        const userId = req.params.userId
        // do something with this userId, for example look up in DB
        return res.status(200).json({userId: `Requested userId is ${userId}`})
        )        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Bad request.' })
    }
})

// add more user endpoints here
// with router.post, router.put, router.delete, whatever you need to do

module.exports = router
```